# I'm trying to create a price calculator app for a hardware strore

Tags: c#, list, class

I want to add every item of the store to a list and calculate the selling price of the item using another class (which I haven't created yet) but I'm struggling to create the list so it adds the instance of the class "Item". Using .Net Core 3.1. This is my code:

PS: The class is in a new tab in VisualStudio

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StockPriceCalculator
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();
            Item nails = new Item("Nails", 5.5);

            list.Add(nails);
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public Item(string name, double price)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your `class Item` is meant to be immutable then you should change the properties to `{ get; }` and not `{ get; set; }`.

Comment: The `price` would be better as `decimal` since it is currency.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Yep: the `double` and `float` (aka `Single`) types must never be used to represent currency/money values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i didnt understand you but why you dont create a list of "item"?

Like that:

```
         public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var list = new List<Item>();
                Item nails = new Item("Nails", 5.5);

                list.Add(nails);
            }
        }
        public class Item
        {
            public Item(string name, double price)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.price = price;
            }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public double price { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: oooh thanks, i didn't think of the way you did it

Comment: Great! pls vote my answer and mark it green when you can! good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of `Item` objects then create a `List<Item>`, not a `List<Tuple<string, double>>`. If you create the latter then you can only add `Tuple<string, double>` objects to it.

Comment: I want it to have 2 variables - name and price

Comment: @KristiyanArnaudov, so what? You are creating an `Item` object with those two variables, not a `Tuple<string, double>`. You need a list that can store the type of object you have. What type of object do you have? An `Item`, right? So create a `List<Item>`.